# How to log in with passport.js after resetting the password in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, passport-local

I am working with passport.js for authentication.

I have an issue which I want to resolve:

Whenever user want to `reset` his `password`, I send an email of `password reset link` to him with `token id`.

And he can `reset` his `password` after clicking that link, but after resetting password,

I want the user being redirect to `dashboard page` instead of `log in page`.

I try to find out solution with passport.js but didn't get any luck.

Can someone give me any idea to resolve this issue?

***Thank You***

Comment: Create function in passport.js. And when your coming to end of main code call the function.

Comment: Hey @Abdulla, Can you elaborate about the function, since i didn't understand what the function will do?

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/functions-in-javascript-2-0/0/1 check this and see bro

Comment: Can you up me your code related to this bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the user resets the password you need to authenticate the user on user's behalf.

Code would look something like this

```
app.post('/resetpassword', function(req, res, next) {
  /*
       code to reset the password
  */

  // append username and new password to req.body
  // assuming passport still uses username and password as field indicator

  req.body.username= "user_name";
  req.body.password= "user_new_password";

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      if (!user) { return res.sendStatus(401); }

      // it is your responsibility to establish the session 
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
         if (err) { return next(err); }

         return res.rediect("to_users_dashboard_path");
      });
 })(req, res, next);
});
```

Note: while using custom callback, it is applications responsibility to establish the session, see [Custom Callback](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/)